# Xcode 5 not showing iCloud in Debug Navigator

Tags: ios, debugging, xcode5, icloud

I am writing an iOS 7 app using iCloud integration. I should have everything set up properly but I am not seeing the iCloud Tab in the Debug Navigator while debugging. Only CPU and Memory.

The apps works perfectly fine with iCloud, no problems here.

Are there any obvious things I should be checking? I haven't found much regarding this issue anywhere else so please excuse the question in this platform.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I assume you're referring to this? "The debug navigator displays gauges that provide insight into how your app is performing. For example, the CPU gauge shows a readout of your app’s CPU usage, making it easy to spot unexpected spikes. Depending on the capabilities of your app and the characteristics of its destination, gauges can report your app’s impact on memory, iCloud, OpenGL ES, energy, and the CPU." From [this Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/DebugYourApp/DebugYourApp.html).

Comment: Yes exactly. So my app should be showing the iCloud tab but for some reason it just doesn't.

Comment: Could it be that I manage Core Data from an NSObject and not in the AppDelegate?

Comment: I am seeing this also, but only with one particular app. It is called the iCloud Debug Gauge.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following steps (all in Xcode) and found a solution.

1. Turn OFF iCloud in Target > Capabilities
2. Quit Xcode
3. Restart Xcode
4. Turn ON iCloud again in the Capabilities.

The iCloud Debug Gauge is again appearing below CPU and Memory.

Comment: Not working for me too. This bug is commemorating one year anniversary.